# How do I split a list of first and last names apart?

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to print only the first names from a .txt list into a new text file.

The .txt list looks like this (each pair of names on its own line, with many more names than shown here):

```
Smith, James
Doe, John
White, Susan
```

Here's my current code:

```
fname = input("Please enter the file name for your list of names: ")
infile = open(fname,"r")
data = infile.read()

outfile = open("student-firstnames.txt", "w")

first = data.split(",")[-1]
print(first, file=outfile)

print("First names have been written to student-firstnames.txt.")
```

This gives me only the very last first name, but I want an entire list of only first names.  What can I do to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Python 3 you could do it like this:

```
fname = input("Please enter the file name for your list of names: ")

with open(fname, "r") as infile, open("student-firstnames.txt", "w") as outfile:
    for line in infile:
        firstname = line.strip().split(', ')[-1]
        print(firstname, file=outfile)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try the following:

```
first = [i.split(", ")[1] for i in data.split("\n")]
print(first, file=outfile)
```

This splits the data by newline and then gets the part after the comma, which is the first name.

Comment: You can also use the `splitlines()` method.

Comment: great - this got me a list of only first names; but the new file looks like:  ['James', 'John', 'Susan'] - is there any way to remove the [ ] and ' ' and get them all on their own line?

Comment: @eeseitz i think you want only the first names, `smith,doe,white`.

Comment: sorry for the confusion - their first names are james, john, susan.  would like to get them all on their own lines though

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate over the file object to process each line of the file one at a time:

```
with open(fname) as infile:
    for line in infile:
        ...
```

For example, you could use this to get a list of the first names for each line in the file:

```
with open(fname) as infile:
    first_names = [line.strip('\n').split(', ')[1] for line in infile]
```

Comment: The newline character may not be needed for `strip()` since it defaults to stripping whitespaces.

Comment: @evambivalence Oh, I see from the accepted answer -- you wanted someone to write your code for you.  I thought you wanted to learn how to do it in general.

Comment: thank you for the help - i tend to learn better first seeing the correct method and examining it from there; which is what happened with the answer I accepted.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this also to get the names at index 1.

```
fname = input("Please enter the file name for your list of names: ")
infile = open(fname,"r")
outfile = open("student-firstnames.txt", "w")
x = '\n,'.join([line.split(', ')[1].strip() for line in infile])
outfile.write(x)
outfile.close()
infile.close()
```

**Output:**

```
James
,John
,Susan
```

Comment: thanks - i tried this one, but it resulted in the entire list as was, just without commas.

Comment: try now.. yep it prints only the first name without any comma.

Comment: this is almost perfect - thank you.  What do you think about this - I'm getting my output on individual lines (good) but with commas preceding each first name now:  , John